# Cigar shops in Saudi Arabia

Tags: shopping, saudi-arabia

I'm currently near Jeddah, Saudi Arabia. I've heard that the country is famous for its tobacco. I was thinking of taking some good quality cigars back with me to India. Could someone please recommend some tourist-accessible shops, preferably in the big malls or the nearby area (like the Red Sea Mall or the Mall of Arabia) where I could get them?

Comment: I'm sorry, this appears to be a "shopping" question. Shopping questions are not allowed on this site because prices and availability may change rapidly.

Comment: I'm not asking the price anywhere in my question. As far as availability goes, I'm asking for tobacco shops in KSA. Not the availability of tobacco in those shops.

Comment: This looks alright to me. It doesn't seem far removed from 'Is there somewhere to buy toiletries at such-and-such airport?'

Comment: @ReddHerring: If the question was "*Are* there any cigar shops in Jeddah", it would be appropriate.  But asking for recommendations of *good* shops makes it opinion-based.

Comment: @Nate I think that depends on what one means by 'good'. I interpreted 'good' to mean the much the same as a plumbers' merchant is good for taps and washers when compared to a general DIY store.

Comment: I don't think deleting "good" makes this any more on-topic. "Where can I do X in area Y?" is essentially asking us to write a tourist guide, and we don't do that.